# KDB: convert millisecond epoc to date

Tags: kdb

I have a table t with a string column tDate.

```
select tDate from t

tDate
----------
1542776400000
1542776400000
1542776400000
1542776400000
1542776400000
1542776400000
1540958400000
1542776400000
1542776400000
1542776400000
1542776400000
```

I want to convert this to a string with MM/dd/YYYY format.

but I need to drop the last 3 characters then convert it to date. But somehow, the below statement does not work correctly:

```
select "P"$-3_tDate from t
```

How is this wrong and how do I translate it to the "MM/dd/YYYY" string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would go about this:

- Convert to string type using `string` - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#string
- Pad the strings to count of 10 using `$` - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/strings/#pad
- Convert to a timestamp type with cast using type p - `"P"$`
- Convert that to the necessary temporal types using `mm`dd`year - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#cast
- Format with zero-colon - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#prepare-text

  ```
    q)t:([]10#1542776400000)
    q)select "/"0:`mm`dd`year$\:"P"$10$string x from t
    x
    ------------
    "11/21/2018"
    "11/21/2018"
    "11/21/2018"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the `long` values to `string`  :

```
q)select `date$"P"$-3_/:string tDate from t
tDate
----------
2018.11.23
2018.11.21
2018.11.21
```

Converting the `date` to  "MM/dd/YYYY" format can be done by:

```
q)f:{ d:"." vs x; "/" sv (d 1;d 2;d 0)}
q)select f each  string `date$"P"$-3_/:string tDate from t
tDate
------------
"11/23/2018"
"11/21/2018"
"11/21/2018"
"11/21/2018"
```

If you are interested in any other format then you have to manipulate the string be defining a custom function like `f` above.

Or you can explore [datetimeQ](https://github.com/aa1024/datetimeQ) GitHub library which supports the excel style formatting.

e.g.

```
q).dtf.format["d mmmm, dddd ,yyyy"; 2018.06.18];
"18 June, Tuesday ,2018"
```